# jQuery Reel Plugin: showing or hiding the reel image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-reel

Excuse my English.

I tried to use the [jQuery Reel Plugin](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) and it works perfectly on my html file.

```
 <img src="DSCN0691.jpg" width="210" height="186"
  class="reel"
  id="image1"
  data-images="fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702">
```

But if I add the script through `document.innerHTML`, it doesn't work at all.

The image will show up, but I can't reel it.

```
document.getElementById('Hello').innerHTML='<img src="fish/DSCN0691.JPG" width="210" height="186" class="reel" id="image2" data-images="fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702">';
```

I also tried the `element.setAttribute(name, value)` function, 
or loaded the whole html file using jQuery.
But it turns out the same way...

Have no idea what to do now.

Or are there any other solution that I can show and hide the reel image dynamically ?

Thanks a lot.

Down here are the whole script and project.

[JQuery Reel Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2uwt4unffnwmdiu/360%20Degree.zip)

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {       

document.getElementById('Hello').innerHTML='<img src="fish/DSCN0691.JPG" width="210" height="186" class="reel" id="image2" data-images="fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702">';

 }
 </script>
```

```
<head>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.reel.js' ></script>
</head>

<body>  
  <div id="Hello"></div>    
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this);">

  <img src="DSCN0691.jpg" width="210" height="186"
    class="reel"
    id="image1"
    data-images="fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reel plugin is initializing all images with the class "reel" on document load. If you change the HTML Dom afterwards, you need to initialize the added image. You can do this by the following javascript instead:

```
$('#image').reel({
    images: 'fish/DSCN####.JPG|691..702'
});
```