# jQuery Reel Plugin loading the reel image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope anyone familiar with jQuery Reel Plugin can help me.

I have a table that dynamically loads images and on those images is an `onclick` function that is supposed to change the reel image to the corresponding cell item. The sprite is not changing away from the default one that is hard-coded.

I understand vaguely that I have to initialize the dynamic images with the `"reel"` class, but adding the attribute `class="reel"` doesn't do anything.

There is another question asking 
[the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881705/jquery-reel-plugin-showing-or-hiding-the-reel-image-dynamically)

-- but I don't know jQuery and don't know how to apply the answer to my own project.

```js
function previewIt(item) {
    var reel = document.getElementById("previewReel");
    reel.dataset.image = item.id + "sprite.png";
}

function headCatalogLoader() {
    var table = document.getElementById("headCatalog");
    var img = 2;
    var uID = 8;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);

        for (var k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {  // 2 is because 3 columns
            var skinTone = "none";
            var cell = row.insertCell(k);

            if (k == 0) {
                skinTone = "lgt";
            }
            else if (k == 1) {
                skinTone = "med";
            }
            else if (k == 2) {
                skinTone = "drk";
            }

            cell.innerHTML = "<img src=\"headimgs/head" + skinTone + img + ".png\" id=\"head" + uID + skinTone + "\" onclick=\"previewIt(this)\" class=\"reel\">";

            uID--;
        }
        img--;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/jquery.reel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="headPreview">
    <img src="head1med.png" height="800"
            id="previewReel"
            class="reel"
            data-image="head1medsprite.png"
            data-frames="8"
            data-footage="4">
</div>
```

I apologize if the code makes you cringe. If it's at all possible I'd like to do it purely in JavaScript, if not then a brief explanation would really help me out. Thank you friends.

Comment: Do you want reel effect in side cell on image? or only in `previewReel` image?

Comment: @saAction the image should change only in previewReel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement :

- You have a table, showing image dynamically
- You want to apply reel only on image `id="previewReel"` when user `click` on the image from dynamically loaded images

> Solution :
>
> - You need to change main image `#previewReel` `reel` image runtime.
> - `$("#previewReel").reel("image", $(item).attr('src'));`

Check below:

```js
headCatalogLoader();

function headCatalogLoader() {
    var table = document.getElementById("headCatalog");
    var img = 2;
    var uID = 8;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);

        for (var k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {  // 2 is because 3 columns
            var skinTone = "none";
            var cell = row.insertCell(k);

            if (k == 0) {
                skinTone = "lgt";
            }
            else if (k == 1) {
                skinTone = "med";
            }
            else if (k == 2) {
                skinTone = "drk";
            }

            cell.innerHTML = "<img src=\"https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=65" + uID + "\" id=\"head" + uID + skinTone + "\" onclick=\"previewIt(this)\"  \>";

            uID--;
        }
        img--;
    }
}

function previewIt(item) {
    $("#previewReel").reel("image", $(item).attr('src')); ///this line will apply new reel 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="headPreview">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"  width="210" height="186"
            id="previewReel"
            class="reel"
            data-image="https://picsum.photos/200/200"
            data-frames="8"
            data-footage="4"
            data-revolution="800"
            />

</div>

<br><br>
<ul>
<li>Runtime table image loaded:</li>
<li>Click on any image, to load its reel effect above</li>
</ul>
<table id="headCatalog"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually wanted to change the reel image to the corresponding sprite using the table image's ID but was able to figure it out based on your code. This is what ended up working the way I wanted:

$("#previewReel").reel("image", $(item).attr('id') + "sprite.png");